# Android rich text editor area is not editable

Tags: java, javascript, php, android, cross-browser

I've a problem in the Android Browser or Web View with loading sites that embed a "Rich Text Editor" inside, like [tinyMce](http://www.tinymce.com/tryit/basic.php) or [Kevinroth](http://www.kevinroth.com/rte/demo.htm).

The editable text area inside the site isn't select-able / editable "when enabling the JS in my webview" in the browser / Web view, when I touch on the editable area the page zooms in/ out.

This happens for me with a lot of similar sites that contains Rich Text Editor inside.

- My Code :

  ```
  @Override
  protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
      super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
      setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
      webView = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.webView1);
  webView.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
  webView.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient() {
      public boolean shouldOverrideUrlLoading(WebView view, String url) {
          // TODO Auto-generated method stub
          view.loadUrl(url);
          return true;
      }
  });
   WebSettings webSettings = webView.getSettings();
   webSettings.setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
   webSettings.setDomStorageEnabled(true);
   webView.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
   webView.getSettings().setDomStorageEnabled(true);
   webView.getSettings().setPluginState(PluginState.ON);
  webView.setWebChromeClient(new WebChromeClient());
   webView.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
   webView.getSettings().setJavaScriptCanOpenWindowsAutomatically(true);

   webView.loadUrl("http://www.tinymce.com/tryit/basic.php");
  }
  ```

Any help..?!

Comment: can you show the `setWebViewClient` part?

Comment: @OsamaEspil It's also happens with the Android Web Browser, not only my web view.

Comment: I tried my simple browser application and I can simply write in the edit text within the page. so maybe you are missing a point

Comment: @OsamaEspil I added my code to the original post above.

Comment: And my only way to get the editable area is to disable JS and that causes in viewing only the HTML of the page.

Comment: I tried all your settings everything is fine... can you add the `webViewClient()` and 'WebChromeClient()' codes please?

Comment: @OsamaEspil I'm using the "android.webkit.WebChromeClient;
&& android.webkit.WebViewClient;" not mine.

Answer (score 0):

It seems that the problem is in Android API 2.2 and 2.3, because when i tested my app on higher APIs it works fine.

But, it stills a problem to this APIs :(

Comment: Maybe this is the reason, because im using API 11 in my browser